# Xml Read Operation

Tags: xml, android-studio, xmlreader

I am working in android studio. I have an xml file. When I try to read it, I can read the first line. How do I read the second and hundreds of other lines with the same levels?

```
     while (event!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
                    String name =Ayristir.getName();     /////XmlPullParser Ayristir
                    Log.d(TAG, "Name is: " + name);

                    if (event==XmlPullParser.START_TAG){

                        data_path=Ayristir.getAttributeValue(null,"data-path");
                        data_duration=Ayristir.getAttributeValue(null,"data-duration");
                        data_title=Ayristir.getAttributeValue(null,"data-title");
                        int a=Ayristir.getEventType();
                        int b=Ayristir.getLineNumber();

--------------------------------------

<ul>
<li data-path="data1" data-title="title1" data-duration="K. Karaca:"/>    //I'm reading this line
|
<li data-path="data2" data-title="title2" data-duration="R. Olcay:"/>
|
<li data-path="data3" data-title="title3" data-duration="Okuyan:"/>
|
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

solution;

```
while (event!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            String name =Ayristir.getName();
            Log.d(TAG, "Name is: " + name);

            if (event==XmlPullParser.START_TAG){

                if (Ayristir.getAttributeValue(null,"data-title")!=null) {

                    data_path=Ayristir.getAttributeValue(null,"data-path");
                    data_duration=Ayristir.getAttributeValue(null,"data-duration");
                    data_title=Ayristir.getAttributeValue(null,"data-title");

                    topla=data_path+"-->"+data_duration+"-->"+data_title;
                    list.add(topla);

                }

            }
            event=Ayristir.next();

        }
```